# spring boot database change with single entity and repository

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to make an application so that, the database its using will change depending on where it is installed. The database choice will be made just once while installing. For example the application installed on a server with MySQL DB would use MySQL, and the one installed on a server with MongoDB would use Mongo.

Everything until here is okay, but I want to use the same entity and repository for different DBs.

- Is it possible?
- With which annotations should I bind my entities?
- Would a repository implementing both MongoRepository and CrudRepository do the job?
- What about the Mongo ObjectId, MySQL id compatibility?
- How bad an idea that MySQL not using foreign key schema?

In short, I have an application currently working on MongoDB, and I want it to work on MySQL too (Oracle and MsSQL too would be awesome) with minimal code writing.

Comment: I think you will have many problems with Schema incompatibilities - the methodologies are too different to interchange this way.